# CakePHP redirection issue while changing hosting

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, hosting, amazon-lightsail

I am migrating a CakePHP project from cPanel to the AWS Lightsail apache server. I have zipped all the files from cPanel and uploaded them on my instance. Started the apache server and hosted the project on the instance IP.

The issue is everything is working fine on the cPanel hosted website but in the AWS instance many pages are not working and the data is also not displaying from the database. Some functionalities like login and signup are also not working.

I have started all the PHP errors and also in CakePHP errors. In starting I got the permission errors but now I am not getting any errors and still, functionalities are not working. I have followed all the steps from CakePHP's official documentation. Started the mod_rewrite but still not able to find the issue.

I have checked all the apache error logs but didn't find any. I don't know cakePHP much as I am only hosting the project.

Please help...

Comment: Did you move the database to somewhere that it's accessible? Update the connection details for that?

Comment: Yes, @GregSchmidt Database is accessible.

Comment: Probably some details about what "not working" actually means would help.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Some database operations are not working. Some redirection issues are there means the application is not running as expected in my local system. Whereas It is working perfectly fine in cPanel.

Comment: Those aren't details, they are generalities. When a database operation fails, what was it trying to do? What error message did you get? Otherwise, when you say "database operations are not working", about all we can do is ask the question that I did above.

Comment: Errors like particular column not found, some variables are undefined in code @GregSchmidt

Comment: If they are new columns that just have been added recently, then you probably just need to clear the model cache. Otherwise, if you still won't provide any specifics of exact error messages, stack trace, and code that the error is happening in, then there's not much more we can do for you.